# Page refreshing repeatedly after login using firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

After logging in, the page to which the user is redirected is refreshing repeatedly.
Here is the javascript code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.

    window.location="comingsoon.html";
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;



  } else {
    // No user is signed in.


  }
});

function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });

}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unsubscribe from the event listening function `onAuthStateChanged` after you execute your code. To do this you can write :

```
const unsubscribeAfterAuth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {


    window.location="comingsoon.html";
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;


  } else {
    // No user is signed in.


  }
});
unsubscribeAfterAuth();
```

This way you won't get updates after the first `onAuthStateChanged` as your function won't be listening to the event after the first call.

Comment: using this i am not able to login

Comment: Can you try putting the `unsubscribeAfterAuth();` inside the success callback of    
 `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass)` ?